# importing csv file with custom delimiter in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm doing mysql in my terminal as well as in my cmd.

I have a table :

```
mysql> create table stu (sno int, name char(10));
```

It's CSV file (b.csv):

```
sno, name
1,a
2,b
3,"c,d"
```

I imported that in mysql :

```
mysql> load data local infile 'd://b.csv' into table stu  fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 rows;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from stu;
+------+------+
| sno  | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | b    |
|    3 | c,d  |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I change the default delimiter alone :
[image: notepad]

[image: cmd]

I have another file with a custom delimiter and a custom quotechar (a.csv):

```
*rno*-*name*
*1*-*ron*
*3*-*vince*
*5*-*Abi-nav*
```

when I import this into mysql,

```
mysql> load data local infile 'd://a.csv' into table stu1 fields terminated by "-"
enclosed by "*" lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 rows;
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                   |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1262 | Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from stu1;
+------+------------+
| sno  | name       |
+------+------------+
|    1 | ron*
*3   |
 |   5 | *Abi-nav*
+------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I get this problem only when I change the default quotechar from `"` into other characters in both Ubuntu and in Windows.
Why I get this warning and this output??? How to solve this?
Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT :**
I tried as said by in the answer:

```
mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> load data local infile '/home/data.csv' into table stu fields terminated by "-" enclosed by '*' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 rows;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.19 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from stu;
+------+---------+
| sno  | name    |
+------+---------+
|    1 | ron     |
|    3 | vince   |
|    5 | Abi-nav |
+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then here you go :

```
mysql> load data local infile '/home/a.csv' into table stu fields terminated by "-" enclosed by '|' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 rows;
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 1 warning (0.09 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                   |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1262 | Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from stu;
+------+------------+
| sno  | name       |
+------+------------+
|    1 | ron|
|3   |
|    5 | |Abinav|
 |
+------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Again I got the warning. Why that happens???

Comment: Check the line endings with some thing that will show you the hex codes at the end of the line

Comment: Which OS does the file come from which is causing you a problem

Comment: @RiggsFolly Check my edits

Comment: Get a hex dump of that csv file; I think the problem will be more obvious with that.

Comment: Can you be more clear with this? Also can you specify that in the answer section?

Comment: what is the version of your mysql?

Answer (score 0):

```
*-*name*
*1*-*ron*
*3*-*vince*
*5*-*Abi-nav*
```

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.20    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table stu1 (sno int, name char(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.23 sec)

mysql> load data local infile '/data/data.csv' into table stu1 fields terminated by "-" enclosed by "*" lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 rows;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from stu1;
+------+---------+
| sno  | name    |
+------+---------+
|    1 | ron     |
|    3 | vince   |
|    5 | Abi-nav |
+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

it is working in mysql version - 8.0.20

Answer (score 0):

Under windows i needed to change termination. so that it runs

MySQL 8.0.22

```
Load data infile 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/a.csv' 
into table stu 
fields terminated by "-"
enclosed by "*" 
lines terminated by '\r\n' 
ignore 1 LINES;
```

The main problem that i see, is that we can't see your csv file further you seem to switch between operating system Windows and linux.

Like i showed in my example the csv was produced in windows and had so `\r\n` as line termination, and this is what the MySQL interpreter had problems with, when i used `\n\`allone.

It had nothing to do with field termination or enclosure.

Comment: What changes would you do in Ubuntu?

Comment: if you use the same file, yes, as is said in my answer, you need to check the file in a hex editor if you have still problems

Comment: Can you be more specific and edit your answer with that?

Comment: no i can't try your load with my parameters, and see if that yields any result. else do that what said use a hex editor like pspad or notepad++ and see what is actually there

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be due to line termination (on Windows \r\n, on Unix/Linux \n) 
You can try with a program like Notepad++, set the line termination to \n. 
After delete all line break and recreate the line break. 
If the load statement works, that was the issue.